# How To Upload Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

I am getting the following error whilst uploading a file.

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'category_id'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'
>   for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   AddProduct(Int32, System.String,
>   Single, System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String)' in
>   'Ecommerce.Controllers.AdminController'.
>   To make a parameter optional its type
>   should be either a reference type or a
>   Nullable type. Parameter name:
>   parameters

I am using a dialog box.

**The View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false, 
            resizable: false
            })
    });

</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Upload files">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {%>
            <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/> </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
        <% } %>
</div>

<p>
    <label for="image_name">image_name:</label>
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">Upload File</a>

    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("image_name", "*") %>
</p>
```

**The Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(int category_id, string product_name, float product_price, string product_desc, string weight, string image_name, string img_content, string available_qty, string isFeature)
{

    foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            string filecontent = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(file.ContentType));

            image_name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            img_content = Path.GetFileName(file.ContentType);

            file.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }

    AdminImplementation _adminImplementation = new AdminImplementation();

    Boolean isfeature = Convert .ToBoolean(isFeature);

    if (isfeature)
    {
        isFeature = "Featured";
    }
    else
    {
        isFeature = "NotFeatured";
    }


    int i = _adminImplementation.addproduct(category_id, product_name, product_price, product_desc, weight,image_name ,img_content ,available_qty ,isFeature );

    ViewData["succm"] = "Product added successfully";
    return View();
}
```

Please suggest some useful answers.

Thanks

Ritz

Comment: We're going to need the method signature also.

Comment: Now that I've fixed your answer up, please supply the ViewResult that renders the page initially.  I need to know where the missing values are.  Furthermore, if you don't know why this error is occuring I recommend you visit www.asp.net/mvc/ as it seems you're not understanding some basic elements of MVC architectures in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're not providing all the parameters required for a specific ActionResult.  `category_id` isn't being provided to `AddProduct`. You'd need to show us your code for us to be able to find out what's really going wrong.

How are you calling that ActionResult?

Answer (score 1):

```
**UPLOADING IMAGE AND SAVING PATH IN THE DATABASE
________________________________________________________________________________________
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
            <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>          
           <form action="Recent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
            </form>          
        </div>


</body>
</html>
____________________________________________________________________________________________

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.ParameterParser;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class Recent
 */
@WebServlet("/Recent")
@MultipartConfig
public class Recent extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Recent() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Sample  s1=new Sample();
         final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images";
         if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
                try {
         List<FileItem> multiparts = new 
                            ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                    for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                        if(!item.isFormField())
                        {
                            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                            String Path= "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images/" +name;


                          s1.connecting(Path);


                        }
                    }

                        request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                   request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
                }          

            }else{
                request.setAttribute("message",
                                     "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
            }



                request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(request, response);




    }

}
__________________________________________________________________________________________
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import dbconnections.Connections;



public class Sample {
    Connections con=new Connections();

    public void connecting(String Path)
    {
        Connection conn=con.Connect();

        PreparedStatement pst;
        String query="INSERT INTO Student1 (Path) values (?)";
       try {

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1,Path);
            pst.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```